# means, std deviation, variance and skewness of image

Tags: c++, opencv, mean, variance, standard-deviation

This code split images to smaller tiles and to find mean value of these tiles and to write those values to file. i want to calculate the variance and skewness too. please help

```
for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; r += m)
    for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; c += n)
    {
        Mat tile = img(Range(r, min(r + m, img.rows)),
            Range(c, min(c + n, img.cols)));

        Scalar MScalar,StdScalar;  
        meanStdDev(tile,MScalar,StdScalar);
        cout<<"\n Blue Channel Avg is "<<MScalar.val[0];
        cout<<"\n Green Channel Avg is "<<MScalar. val[1];
        cout<<"\n Red Channel Avg is "<<MScalar. val[2];     
        cout<<"\nBlue channel std dev is "<<StdScalar.val[0];
        cout<<"\nGreen Channel std dev is "<<StdScalar. val[1];
        cout<<"\nRed Channel std dev is "<<StdScalar. val[2]<<"\n";
        int m[6] = { MScalar.val[0], MScalar.val[1], MScalar.val[2], StdScalar.val[0],  StdScalar.val[1], StdScalar.val[2] };
        Mat M = Mat(1, 6, CV_32S, m);
        outdata<< M << "\n";
        cout<<M<<endl; 

    }
    outdata<<endl;
 }
}

waitKey(); 

return 0; 
}
```

Comment: And your problem is...?

Comment: So look up the formulas for variance and skewness and implement them. Variance is trivial since you already have the standard deviation. Skewness might be a bit trickier.

Comment: is there an inbuilt function for variance, similar to mean and std dev in opencv?

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation

"In other words the standard deviation σ (sigma) is the square root of the variance of X"

Meaning, if you have the standard deviation, all you need to do is std*std to get the variance.

As for the Skewness : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness

You can see from the formula what you need to do is the sum of the value minus the mean and divide it by the std, all of this to the power of 3.

An example for the hue channel would be:

```
float skewness;
for (int x = 0; x<channelHue.rows; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y<channelHue.cols; y++) {
        skewness += pow(((channelHue.at<int>(x, y) - mean)/std), 3);
    }
}
```